# Are you sure popup on Contact Form 7

Tags: jquery, javascript, plugin-contact-form-7

I have a contact form built with Contact Form 7. What I want to do is when the user hits the submit button to throw up a pop up window with a notice asking if their sure they want to submit the form with an ok or cancel button. I've found the hook 'wpcf7_before_send_mail'. I was hoping there might be something i could do in the additional settings. Something like

```
wpcf7_before_send_mail: "javascript here"
```

But when I have tried to just get an action to work like this say:

```
before_send_mail: "window.alert("hello");"
```

It just submits the form without doing anything.

How would I get a popup to appear with an ok and cancel button, ok submitting form and cancel breaking the action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `wpcf7_before_send_mail` is a hook that is triggered after form submission, so it isn't what you're looking for.

You should make a javascript script that triggers when the user hits the submit button on your page.  It's implementation could be a simple using javascript [`confirm()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.confirm) - [example](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-confirm) - or using a modal box to ask the user to confirm his choice.

Comment: Hi, is there a way do you know to add a onclick to a submit button?

Comment: Yes, jQuery. `$('your-button').click(function){...});`

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way, hook into the `on submit` there are several ways to do this and a simple google search for "javascript (or jquery) confirm submit" Will return quite a few. Here is one way

```
 var el = document.getElementById('FORMIDHERE');

 el.addEventListener('submit', function(){
     return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit this form?'); }, false);
```

I'm sure this could be factored into jQuery but JS is not my skill set. If you wanta get fancy with the confirm you can use something like [alertify.js](http://fabien-d.github.com/alertify.js/) to style the confirm box.

Bottom line, there is really no need to hook into the plugin at all.